# What difference does a copper coffeepot make?

Tags: brewing-process, flavor, equipment

As the tongue twister and song goes,

> All I want is a proper cup of coffee
> Made in a proper copper coffeepot

Even going so far to rather having tea than using a coffeepot made out of tin or iron.

Having only experience with glass and steel coffeepots, I wonder what's so special about a copper coffeepot. Is there a big difference in taste?

Comment: Do you mean as a brewing vessel like a French press or a moka pot? Or also as a container into which the coffee drips from a paper filter for instance?

Comment: @JJJ the song doesn't really say, does it? But I've always interpreted as the receptacle in which the brewed coffee is collected and from which it is poured into a cup for drinking.

Answer (score 1):

Copper conducts heat well, so a copper kettle will boil a bit faster than other materials.

I have a copper boiler on my espresso machine and an antique Georgian copper coffee pot (like the one in the tongue twister). Both are pretty and make good coffee but I don’t think the copper gets any credit.

Answer (score 1):

There was a time long ago when it was fashionable to build kettles with solid copper. The reason for this has more to do with the heat capacity and conductance capabilities of copper and also because it is relatively easy to work (compared to modern alloyed metals like stainless steel). No doubt the song refers more to a personal preference, perhaps nostalgic in nature, than to a genuinely better tasting brew since, you know, hot water is hot water.

Answer (score -1):

Copper is a better conductor of heat which leadins to uniform heating and "cooking" of the beans.